# Python subprocess wait until specific string on stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a subprocess I start via `subprocess.Popen`. This process never exits until I send a SIGINT. I want to block the execution since a specific string is available on the stdout of the subprocess (lets say `foo`). Is there any "easy" way without create threads and queues? Something like
`myprocess.wait_until("foo")`?

Comment: Parent process continues immediately after starting the subprocess, so it can continuously read its child stdout and signal it when it founds the stop word. The only caveat is that the child should consistently flush after its outputs because pipes are normally buffered.

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
  line = p.stdout.readline()
  if specific_string in line: break
```

source http://bugs.python.org/issue3907